# Frame not appearing when it is supposed to... (ROBLOX GUI)

Tags: user-interface, lua, roblox

I am making an Os module that lets you create remote Operating systems but when the background frame loads in a new window just an random window loads in but it just basically gets "overwritten" by the background frame.

I have a post on scriptinghelpers: https://scriptinghelpers.org/questions/116285/instancenew-but-not-working-as-expected-module

but it seems that no one wants no one on the website knows how to do it

my code for the main Os module:

```
local module = {}

function module.__Version__()
    local ROS = '1.00'
    local ROS = tostring(ROS)
    print('Version: '..ROS)
end


function module.create_environment(master)
    local main = Instance.new('ScreenGui',master)
    main.Name = ("ROS")
    return(main)
end


function module.create_background(env)
    local Frame = Instance.new('Frame',env)
    Frame.Name = ('Background')
    Frame.Size = UDim2.new(2,0,2,0)
    Frame.Position = UDim2.new(0, 0,-0.5, 0)
    Frame.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(0.337255, 0.290196, 1)
    return(Frame)

end


function module.create_taskbar(env)
    local main = Instance.new("Frame",env)
    main.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(0, 0, 0)
    main.Size = UDim2.new(2, 0,0, 45)
    main.Position = UDim2.new(-0.5, 0,1, -45)

    return(main)
end


function module.create_app_button(icon,env,X,Y)
    local Btn = Instance.new('ImageButton',env)
    Btn.Image = (tostring(icon))
    Btn.Size = UDim2.new(0, 49,0, 49)
    Btn.Position = UDim2.new(0, tonumber(X), 0, tonumber(Y))

    return(Btn)
end


function module.create_clone_env(env)
    local coloned_env = env:Clone()
    coloned_env.Parent = env.Parent
end



function module.create_time_gui(env)
    local main = Instance.new('TextLabel',env)
    main.Size = UDim2.new(0, 115,0, 41)
    main.Position = UDim2.new(1, -145,1, -44)
    main.TextColor3 = Color3.new(1, 1, 1)
    main.BackgroundTransparency = 1
    main.TextScaled = true
    main.Font = Enum.Font.Ubuntu

    local assetId = 5990705305
    local InsertService = game:GetService("InsertService")
    local model = InsertService:LoadAsset(assetId)
    model.Time_Manager.Parent = main

    return(main)
end


function module.create_start_button(env)
    local main_button = Instance.new('TextButton',env)
    main_button.Size = UDim2.new(0, 146,0, 45)
    main_button.Position = UDim2.new(0, 0,1, -44)
    main_button.TextColor3 = Color3.new(0, 0, 0)
    main_button.Text = "Start"
    main_button.TextSize = 25
    main_button.Font = Enum.Font.Arial
    main_button.BorderSizePixel = 0

    return(main_button)
end


function module.create_app(env)
    local frame = Instance.new('Frame',env)
    local round = Instance.new("UICorner",frame)
    local top_frame = Instance.new('Frame',frame)
    local exit_button = Instance.new('TextButton',top_frame)
    local assetId = 5995055509
    local InsertService = game:GetService("InsertService")
    local model = InsertService:LoadAsset(assetId)
    round.CornerRadius = UDim.new(0,20)

    frame.Size = UDim2.new(0, 1084,0, 673)
    frame.Position = UDim2.new(0.5, -542,0.5, -336)
    frame.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(1, 1, 1)

    top_frame.Size = UDim2.new(1, 0,0.003, 28)
    top_frame.Position = UDim2.new(0, 0,0, 0)
    top_frame.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(0.611765, 0.611765, 0.611765)
    top_frame.BorderSizePixel = 0

    exit_button.Size = UDim2.new(0, 74,0, 30)
    exit_button.Position = UDim2.new(1, -74,0.5, -15)
    exit_button.Text = ("X")
    exit_button.BorderSizePixel = 0
    exit_button.TextColor3 = Color3.new(1, 1, 1)
    exit_button.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(1, 0, 0)
    exit_button.TextStrokeTransparency = 0
    exit_button.TextSize = 17

    model.LocalScript.Parent = exit_button
    model:Destroy()


    return(frame)
end     




return module
```

Everything works; `create_taskbar()`,`create_time_gui()`,`create_start_button()`
But its just the `create_app()`

This is what my Os-module made:

[image]

This is the OS my Os-module made:

[image]

As i said the background overwrites my `create_app()` is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: For a short-cut:  https://scriptinghelpers.org/questions/116285/instancenew-but-not-working-as-expected-module

Answer (score 1):

If maintaining the element hierarchy is important, try adjusting the [ZIndex](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/GuiObject/ZIndex) of the background frame and the app so that the two aren't fighting for which one appears on top. Elements with smaller numbers for their ZIndex will render first, meaning they will appear behind elements with larger ones.

```
function module.create_background(env)
    local Frame = Instance.new('Frame',env)
    Frame.ZIndex = 1
    -- <a bunch of other code>

    return Frame
end
```

And then make the app's ZIndex higher.

```
function module.create_app(env)
    local frame = Instance.new('Frame', env)
    frame.ZIndex = 2
    -- <a bunch of other code>

    return frame
end
```

But you should be careful. Messing with ZIndices can get really messy really quick. A better alternative would be to just set the app Frame's parent to the background Frame.

Comment: Your code works for the Server side but for the client its not doing what it did before not showing